# Laravel 5.3 use Passport instead of JWT

Tags: php, laravel

I am upgrading a REST backend from Laravel 5.1 to Laravel 5.3 . I have used Tymon JWT package for authentication previously and Entrust for Access Control. I recently read that Laravel 5.3 comes with Passport and scopes to replace this. However, passport looks like Facebook login. How do I make basic Authentication for API using passport. Do I need to use separate package for ACL or scopes can do all the Access Control for me?

Comment: Passport implementing O2Auth, that was a reason why your login looks like fb login.

Comment: But it say API authentication. So I assume I can create a default client for my app. But not sure though

Comment: Yes you can, but Passport more than restfull service authentication, You can use passport too, but in my opinion you can write your token based authentication which one more easy to use.

Comment: @rohitnaidu19 Read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376928/larvel-5-3-passport-jwt-authentication/41395074#41395074